# Stash & Switchee parse order problems

Tags: stash, parse-order, switchee

I have the following blocks of code that I can't seem to to work correctly. The list sets and populates perfectly, but the switchee statement doesn't work. I konw that it has do do with parse order but I can't figure out what is going on. The debug value of for the switchee tag is this:

```
{exp:switchee variable="M00o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr" parse="inward"}
```

It seems as though switchee is running before stash is parsing list_count, is there any way to fix this?

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="buy_now_options" parse_depth="4" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{lv_site_buy_now}" status="open|closed" order_by="entry_id" sort="asc" limit="3"}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:item_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:item_entry_id}
        {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
        {stash:logo}{partner_logo:url}{/stash:logo}
        {stash:base_url}{partner_base_purchase_url}{/stash:base_url}
        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="purchase_urls" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
            {partner_retail_urls}
                {stash:product}{partner_retail_urls:product:title}{/stash:product}
                {stash:url}{partner_retail_urls:url}{/stash:url}
            {/partner_retail_urls}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="buy_now_options" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
    {exp:switchee variable="{exp:stash:list_count name='purchase_urls' context='{item_entry_id}'}" parse="inward" }
        {case value="0"}
            true
            <li><a href="{base_url}" target="_blank"><img src="{logo}" alt="{title} Web Store" /></a></li>
        {/case}
        {case default="yes"}
            false
            <li><a href="{base_url}" data-reveal-id="{url_title}-modal"><img src="{logo}" alt="{title} Web Store" /></a></li>
        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried "nested" or another string after list_count? ...list_count:nested

Comment: I just tried it, but it has the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're simply testing to see if the nested entries are empty or not. Could you not use something like:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="buy_now_options" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
  {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="purchase_urls"}
  {if no_results}Show default link{/if}
  // There must be entries so show them
  {exp:stash:get_list:nested}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```